# How to calculate the average progressively without know the total items?

Tags: php, arrays, math, average, stat

(Language PHP - This question is for any language, particularly I'm using PHP)
For example you have an array of numbers like:

```
$q = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... ); // ... mean you can give more numbers
$i = 0;
$currentAverage = 0;
while ($i < count( $q )) {
    $currentAverage = ($currentAverage + $q[$i]) / 2;  // this is my try
    $i++;
}

echo "The final average is: " . $currentAverage . "<br/>";
```

Obviusly, you can divide by `count( $q )` the sum, but that's not the idea.

I hope you can help me! thanks.

Comment: I don't see the point. Can you explain why you would want to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for an array of the averages from the 1st item through the nth?  (ex. 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5)

Comment: @BizzyBob I want the total average, but not dividing for the total, I'm trying to do an incremental averages.

Comment: I don't understand why you want 'incremental average' in the end, it looks like you just want the average value of the entire set.

Comment: @CUGreen Simply I want to know if it is possible to implement it?

Comment: not sure, maybe this will help.. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106700/incremental-averageing

Comment: Of course you can calculate the running average without an array or keeping all the elements in memory.  You do need to keep the sum of values and the total number.

Answer (score 4):

You can't calculate an "incremental" mean average without knowing the total number of items make up that average.

For example, if you have 10 items that average 5 and you want to add the next item, `X`, you have to give the appropriate "weight" to the newly added item.

For example, to get the next average, you would do

```
(currentAverage * currentNumberOfItems + X) / (currentNumberOfItems + 1)
```

If we say `X` is 7, the new average would be

```
(5 * 10 + 7) / (10 + 1)
= (50 + 7) / 11
= 57 / 11
= 5.181818182
```

It is *impossible* to do this calculation without knowing the current number of items that make up the average (10) beforehand

---

To show you this working in an incremental fashion, here is a `for` loop that keeps track of the average as the loop is running

```
$xs = [1,2,3,4,5];
$average = $xs[0];
for ($count = 1; $count < count($xs); $count++) {
  echo sprintf("average: %0.3f, count: %d" . PHP_EOL, $average, $count);
  $average = ($average * $count + $xs[$count]) / ($count + 1);
}

average: 1.000, count: 1
average: 1.500, count: 2
average: 2.000, count: 3
average: 2.500, count: 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Could use this:

```
$q = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... ); // ... mean you can give more numbers
$i = 0;
$currentAverage = 0;
while ($i < count( $q )) {
    $sliceArr = array_slice($q, 0, $i+1);
    $currentAverage = array_sum($sliceArr) / count($sliceArr);
    $i++;
}

echo "The final average is: " . $currentAverage . "<br/>";
```